# check if two arrays contain similar values

Tags: php

is there a way to check if two arrays have value that is alike, note not equal but alike. something similar to what mysql has with `LIKE` to find words that is similar.

in topten.txt i have the following word:
`WORKFORCE`

in company.txt i have the following url:
`Workforce-Holdings-Ltd`

So basically i would like to search for the word `WORKFORCE` in company.txt and the results output should be `Workforce-Holdings-Ltd`.

Is it possible to do it.

i was maybe thinking preg_grep() perhaps?

Comment: I think it possible to do it, you can convert lower case before use regular expression.

Comment: That would work i think, unfortunately im not so good regx, basic understanding

Comment: I think you can use this web site to try it, which regular expression is you write. https://www.regex101.com/. I think you have more same work, so you can try to use `g` mode.

Comment: Your title says 'two arrays' but your example is just searching one array for a single value - which is it? You also need to define 'similar'. `Workforce` is contained within `Workforce-Holdings-Ltd`, but what about `Work Force`, or `WorkFarce`?

Comment: You can also use `in_array()` ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preg_grep is perfect for this. As long as you are searching array values you can just do something like the following:

```
<?php

$companies = [
    'acme inc',
    'wORkForce-holdings-ltd'
];

$search = 'WORKFORCE';

var_dump(preg_grep('/' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '/i', $companies));
```

Here's an [ideone example](http://ideone.com/94CA9f).

Comment: Perhaps add `\b` assertions on both sides in an attempt to avoid words that contain the search string.

Comment: Possibly. Although I assumed the asked was looking for something similar to SQL `LIKE` syntax where you'd usually just prepend/append a `%` to your query. In that case it'll also return words containing the search query.

Answer (score 1):

You need not use preg match. Instead you can use strpos like:

```
$result=array();
$a=array('WORKFORCE');
$b=array('Workforce-Holdings-Ltd');
foreach($a as $array1){
    foreach($b as $array2){
        if (strpos(strtolower($array2),strtolower($array1)) !== false) {
            $result[] = 'true';
        }
        else {
            $result[] = 'false';
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you an array with true if match is ok or false is match is not ok for all array elements